# How do I delete rows from a tableview in the context of a core data one to many relationship? (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, one-to-many, delete-row

I have a vacation app where in the initial view controller I can get the weather of cities from an API, and when I select a row it segues to another view controller where I can add a to do list to an itinerary. I got everything working, I just can't figure out how to handle deleting rows from the itinerary. When I try to delete a row it says:

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

Heres my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ToDoViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var itineraryTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var editCityName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var editTripName: UITextField!

var myFetchRCTripName: Trip?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}


@IBAction func editTrip(_ sender: Any) {
    if !(editCityName.text!.isEmpty) && !(editTripName.text!.isEmpty){
        myFetchRCTripName!.cityName = editCityName.text
        myFetchRCTripName!.tripName = editTripName.text
        CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()
    } else{
        print ("error")
    }
   
}

@IBAction func addToDo() {
    //add to itinerary
    let itin = Itinerary(context: CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext)
    itin.toDo = itineraryTextField.text
    
    //set owner
    itin.owner = myFetchRCTripName
    myFetchRCTripName!.addToItineraries(itin)
    
    tableView.reloadData()
    CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()

}


}

extension ToDoViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myFetchRCTripName?.itineraries?.count ?? 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    
    if let itin = myFetchRCTripName!.itineraries {
        let itemsOnListArray = itin.allObjects
        let i = itemsOnListArray[indexPath.row] as! Itinerary
        cell.textLabel?.text = i.toDo
    }
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        var itemsOnListArray = myFetchRCTripName!.itineraries?.allObjects
        itemsOnListArray?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        let itemsOnListArray = myFetchRCTripName!.itineraries?.allObjects
        let obj = itemsOnListArray?[indexPath.row] as! Itinerary
        myFetchRCTripName!.removeFromItineraries(obj)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()
    }
}
```